# How to specify a global optional segment of a scope in router.ex?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Suppose, I had a lot of different routes.  Now I want to introduce an optional segment `:language` for a certain scope in `router.ex`. The result would be this:

```
# a small sliver of all the routes

my_site.com/fr/articles/123.html
my_site.com/es/articles/123.html
my_site.com/ru/articles/123.html

my_site.com/jj/articles/123.html # ops! should explode and 
# redirect to the default language

# if the language is missing,
# it gets the default value
my_site.com/articles/123.html
```

That is, when the language parameter is missing, the default value will be used.

How to implement this?

```
  # something like this,
  # but this as is won't work
  scope "/language", MyAppWeb do

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
scope "/:language" do
  resources "/articles", ArticlesController, only: [:index, :show], as: :locale_scoped_articles
end

resources "/articles", ArticlesController
```

This creates two named routes, using the same controller. In this case I elected to change the route name for the scoped version of the routes (to `language_scoped_articles_path`, making it so that the default `articles_path` route helpers will not contain locale scoping. But you could do the reverse instead, depending on whether you want the "usual" route helpers to require the locale to be specified or not.

Comment: As I've pointed out, I have **a lot of** different routes. Your solution will require duplication of almost the entire `router.ex` file content

Comment: Since there's no such thing as an _optional_ scope in Phoenix, perhaps then your best option is to implement your optional routing as a Plug. There's an answer with a problem similar to what you'r attempting to solve here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144877/optional-routing-parameters-in-phoenix-framework